# Regular expression to match pattern "[strApp1]...AppName=TestApp1..."

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string on following pattern:

```
"[strApp1]\nvar1=111,221,21,800b0\nAppName=TestApp1\nlabel=Application1\nbackground=d1b4ad\n\n
[strApp2]\nvar2=111,22,12,288b\nAppName=TestApp2\nlabel=Application2\nbackground=dd2s2\n\n
[strApp3]\nvar3=222,322,22333\nAppName=TestApp3\nlabel=Application3\nbackground=ccc000\n\n"
```

This is generated dynamically so can go to any length repeating the string pattern.

I want two groups in my result collection:

```
[strApp1]
[strApp2]
[strApp3]
```

and

```
TestApp1
TestApp2
TestApp3
```

so it's group of first part of `string[strApp1]` and `AppName`.

I tried the following regular expression but it is not yielding what I need:

```
(?:\[(str[\w]+)+\])+(?:.+)+(?:AppName=([\w+]+)+)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\[(?<app>.*?)].*?AppName=(?<name>.*?)\\n
```

Comment: Thanks Dejan! This works fine when I check in .NET regex tester in browser, but the same when I put into my code in Visual studio it does not match anything!!!!?

Comment: It's working now, have to apply RegexOptions.Singleline. Thanks!